# Census badge can be chosen for any Stack Overflow site now

Tags: discussion, status-completed, badges

If I mistakenly chose a different site than Stack Overflow, can this be corrected? Not a big deal but just curious.

Comment: It's not enabled for *every* site in the network - for instance, Japanese Language doesn't even have a census badge - but this is likely enabled for all of the technical sites.

Comment: @Makoto The Census badge actually is available on the Stack Overflow in Japanese site. If you click "View other eligible sites" on the badge fulfillment page that you reach after taking the survey, you will see the Japanese site if you are a member of it.

Comment: Which site did you pick? I'd be happy to move it.

Comment: @AnitaTaylor:  I'm a member there but [I'm not seeing it in the badge list](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/badges).  Am I missing something here or am I just having one of those days?

Comment: @Makoto It's not you, it's me. I thought you were referring to https://ja.stackoverflow.com/ (the Stack Overflow in Japanese site). You are correct -- we don't offer it on the Japanese Language site. We offer it on 26 sites that are technical in nature.

Comment: Oh, okay then - along the lines of what I had assumed then.   Thanks for clarifying/reassuring me that I wasn't insane @AnitaTaylor.

Comment: @JonEricson appreciate it. It’s in SharePoint.stackexchange.com; Pls move it to StackOverlow

Comment: @JonEricson, any chance you've got time to take a look at my [related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379309)?

Comment: @SamHanley: I'm in a meeting. I'll take a look later today.

Comment: @JonEricson thanks! Sorry to ping you - not trying to hassle anyone about it for my own sake, just wanted to get it in front of the right eyes so that it if the answer is non-trivial, it doesn't turn into a potential problem for too many other people as the number who've taken the survey rises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently missing from SharePoint:

[image: SharePoint]

And awarded on Stack Overflow:

[image: Stack Overflow]

There is a chance you'll get another SharePoint badge, which will mean I'll need to ping a developer to remove it and the condition that will award it each time the badge award process is run.

Comment: Thank you for taking care of this.