# Can I re-access the Census badge site selection page if I closed the completed survey without viewing it initially?

Tags: support, status-completed, survey-2019

I filled out the Developer Survey for 2019, but I haven't received the Census badge. As of last year, the question [I did not earn the Census Badge for this year's survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364515/i-did-not-earn-the-census-badge-for-this-years-survey) indicates that the badge was supposed to be applied automatically, but based on what I'm reading now, it appears that the [Census badge can be chosen for any Stack Overflow site now](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379291/census-badge-can-be-chosen-for-any-stack-overflow-site-now) and there's a page I was supposed to navigate to where I'd select the site for which I wanted it applied.

When I finished the survey, I closed the window without ever seeing this page, and now I can't find a way to get back to it - if I click the survey link again, it simply says "You have either already completed the survey or your session has expired". Is there some other way to get to the page, or did I miss my one shot?

Comment: @kemicofa Seems sad to dirty SO's data just to earn a badge.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not so hard up for the badge that I'm going to mess with the survey by submitting a duplicate submission. I'd hope that there's a better resolution available, and if not, I'm not going to lose sleep over it.

Comment: [Congratulations!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6644/census?userid=3486353)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have browsing history enabled, the page title is "Thank you! - Stack Overflow"

[image]

The link should be similar to

`https://stackoverflow.com/dev-survey/complete?award=[uniqueId]`

Comment: Thanks for this! Hopefully it'll help anyone who ends up in the same situation.

Comment: I've tried to use this link. THe response has right but I haven't badge ;(

Answer (score 3):

You should have reached a page with a button saying: "Get the badge on Stack Overflow". (You can also select another technical site where you have an account, if you prefer.) As you observed, if you navigate away before reaching that page, you will miss your chance to get the badge. We can't easily verify that you actually took the survey either.

That said, if you pinky swear you took the survey all the way to the end, we can manually award the badge for you. (The final question looks something like [this](https://twitter.com/jackz314sci/status/1088179759744339968).)

Comment: Thanks for fixing things up in my case! Yeah, I recall the page - I just had too many tabs going at once and reflexively closed it prematurely.